# archlinux install [linux newbie]

Tags: arch-linux

*device*: surface book 2 / archlinux via usb flash drive

so far, i have:

-trusted platform module disabled

-secureboot disabled

then I did an MBR partitioning with 2 partitions:
1 root (/dev/sda2)
1 swap (/dev/sda1)

these are the following commands I typed after partitioning

**mkswap /dev/sda1**

**swapon /dev/sda1**

**mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda2**

**pacman -Ssy**

after the following command

**pacstrap /mnt base linux-firmware sudo nano**
i got an error on the screenshot
**[image: genfstab -U /mnt >> /mnt/etc/fstab]**

i still went on with this command:
**arch-chroot /mnt**
which was unsuccessful.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your upgrade/install packages are not installed as written in the TTY. Fix `openssl` gpg key. `bash` package is not installed because of this. Try to search on another device the error you encountered with `pacman` before trying to `arch-chroot`. `bash` need to be installed

Comment: thanks! i'm insecure about 

"pacstrap /mnt base linux-firmware sudo nano"

this command got executed properly now, but in my instruction it says

"pacstrap /mnt base linux linux-firmware sudo nano"

so 1x linux is missing and i can't go back ...

it's so bad to be a noob ...